# What does () mean if set as a interface property?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

In the Vue.js source code (`packages/reactivity/src/effects.ts`), I found this:

```ts
export interface ReactiveEffectRunner<T = any> {
  (): T
  effect: ReactiveEffect
}
```

What does `()` mean in the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you want to define a function with other properties you make use of this pattern.

`()` means that the object implementing this interface will be a function which can be called and does not need any params.

`effect` means it has another property called effect.

An example from the docs:

```
type DescribableFunction = {
  description: string;
  (someArg: number): boolean;
};
function doSomething(fn: DescribableFunction) {
  console.log(fn.description + " returned " + fn(6));
}
```

Read about [call signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures)

Answer (score 3):

It means the type is executable as a function.

for example:

```
declare const fn: ReactiveEffectRunner<{ abc: number }>

const result = fn() // { abc: number }
fn.effect // ReactiveEffect
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1&ts=4.6.2&ssl=11&ssc=28&pln=8&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAShCGBjYBLAbhAogM2xZUAvFAN4C+AsAFDUoB2wEATtktHEqhjnsjAK506zADwAVIlHh0QAPlLUoUABQBKAFxQxiqBFz5gmjsnRZ9yapRpUAJvgA28JtEQB7OgGdgUbHSMITbnNgASFREikAI0RNOn4AW0jmKDJZamo3T29nD357b2JfNSgAehLSKJioOMTkq18AOj1ebzLYAK4zFqA)